# Actionscript 2 error if statement

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I am trying to create a if statement, but I get this compolor error:

```
')' expected
Unexpected '}' encountered
```

My function:

```
function hideThumbs():Void {
    contentHolder.thumbHolder._visible = false;
        if (contentHolder.testerHolder._visible = true;) {
        contentHolder.testerHolder._visible = false;
    } else {
        }
    //contentHolder.thumbHolder.alphaTo(0, buttonTime, menuTween, 0, function(){ moveThumbs("out"); });
    //thumbsHidden = true;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try:

```
if (contentHolder.testerHolder._visible == true) {
```

The semicolon has nothing to do there, and you want a comparison operator in there, not an assignment.